# include controller in view laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I got stuck.

My problem is I want 2 sections (navigation, content) that has dynamic data

Here's some code
Main Blade

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="navigation">
            @yield('menu')
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            @yield('content')   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

portfolio blade

```
    @extends('main')

@section('content')
    @foreach($data as $portfolio)
        <a href="portfolio/{!!$portfolio->portfolio_url!!}"><img src='{{ URL::asset("images/$portfolio->picture.jpg") }}'/></a>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

and my navigation blade

```
@extends('main')
@section('menu')
    @foreach($menuknoppen as $menuknop)
            <a href='{{ URL::to("$menuknop->menu_url") }}'>{{$menuknop->menutitle}}</a>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

the portfolio blade has a controller, but also the menu blade has a controller

**Edit1:**

the problem is the navigation isn't showing even if I add static text

**Edit2:**

My controllers
my portfolio controller

```
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(){
        //here comes a whole list with what i've done
        $results = DB::table('projects')->get();
        //return $results;
        $data = array();
        foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
            $data[] = $result;
        }
        return view('portfolio.portfolio')->with('data', $data);
    }
    public function getProject($portfolio_url){
        //this gets the project thats clicked
        $results = DB::select('select * from projects where portfolio_url = ?', array($portfolio_url));
        return view('portfolio.single')->with('data', $results['0']);
    }

}
```

my navigation controller

```
class menuController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    // public function __construct($table){
    //  $results = DB::table($table)->get();

    //     return view('menu')->with('menuknoppen', $results);
    // }
    public function index(){
        $results = DB::table('navigation')->get();

        return view('menu')->with('menuknoppen', $results);
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to include the navigation to you portfolio?

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask the problem Updated

Comment: Where is navigation in your file tree? For example: views/layouts/navigation.

Comment: Am i right that you want to include the navigation inside your portfolio?

Comment: I moved it here views/menu.blade.php, What I found out was the section(menu) is working inside the portfolio blade (this gives a Undefined  variable: menuknoppen), but not in his own blade. I see one other thing I forgot in my above question the navigation blade. Updating

Comment: Im asking if my question is right.

Comment: I want to include the navigation inside my main blade just like the portfolio

Comment: So in your main blade there are two views. The portfolio and the navigation?

Comment: Thats correct I include 2 views

Comment: When you do `view source` are you able to see navigation screen code?

Comment: Try my answer. If it works.

Comment: Gaurav I cannot see somthing in the `view source`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main blade should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navigation">
        @include('menu');
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        @yield('content')   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your portfolio should be:

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')
  @foreach($data as $portfolio)
   <a href="portfolio/{!!$portfolio->portfolio_url!!}"><img src='{{ URL::asset("images/$portfolio->picture.jpg") }}'/></a>
  @endforeach

@stop
```

Navigation field should be:

```
//Don't use extends here
 @foreach($menuknoppen as $menuknop)
        <a href='{{ URL::to("$menuknop->menu_url") }}'>{{$menuknop->menutitle}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Pass multiple data

```
public function index()
{
  $data = //data code;
  $results = // results code
  return view(portfolio.portfolio, compact('data', 'results'));
}
```

Comment: Now the question is how do I add the navigation view inside the main blade?

Comment: I've just do it. I included it. Just try to change your code.

Comment: That true sorry didn't see that! Now i have the same error again Undefined variable: menuknoppen. When you include a view does it execute the controller? because my navigation is comming from a database

Comment: Can i see your controllers? And also how you call this `$menuknoppen`

Comment: I added the controllers

Comment: This code: `$results = DB::table('navigation')->get(); return view('menu')->with('menuknoppen', $results);` transfer it in the `index` of my portfolio controller.

Comment: That worked, but the portfolio part is not showing because the view menu is returned, can i combine these?

Comment: I've added passing of multiple data's

Comment: Yes it works! But the menuController is unnecessary now? And is it impossible to let it stand on it's own

Comment: It's up to you if you wish to use that controller or delete that. Maybe you want to accept this. Tnx

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: No problem. Glad could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed the concept of @yield , @include and @extend

@yield provides a place for you to replace, so when you call @extend in other view you can reuse the template in view which you extend and replace the part with @yield

@include means this part of code is always replaced by the view it defined

So when you are designing a webpage, you need to make sure what is "always called" (use @include) and what could be replaced (use @yield)

As an assisting explanation to aldrin27 working code, I hope this make your mind clearer on the blade template, it rocks! :D